# Programmatically added EditText missing style

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a dialog fragment which has one EditText defined in its layout and a number of other EditTexts added programmatically (because their number may vary). My problem is that the one defined in xml has the default platform style - e.g. blue bar underneath - whereas the programmatically added ones appear to have no style. See screenshot for reference.

How can create an EditText programmatically while maintaining the default style?

How I create the EditTexts:

```
EditText et = new EditText(this.getActivity());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.topMargin = 10;

et.setText("whatever");
et.setLayoutParams(params);

mContainer.addView(et);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create xml resource in Layout folder like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is a template"
    style="@style/my_style" />
```

And then inflate it like below in your code:

```
TextView myText = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tvtemplate, null);
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks. inflating from XML with a style set works. I just used style="@android:style/Widget.EditText".

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code snippet.

```
EditText et = new AppCompatEditText(this.getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet

```
Drawable drawable = editText.getBackground();
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
int osVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN;
if(sdk < osVersion) {
    editText.setBackgroundDrawable(originalDrawable);
} else {
    editText.setBackground(originalDrawable);
}
```

Comment: This would only work for the background. I want to make sure other style elements would also match.